# Issue with jQuery Chechbox checked or not

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change a css dispaly property of div by selecting and unselecting a checkbox following this script:

```
<td>
 <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
 <label for="c1"> <span> </span>  Display : None  </label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" /> 
 <label for="c2"><span> </span> Display : Inline   </label>
</td>
```

and the jquery is:

```
 $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if($('#c2').attr('checked');){
     $('#hiddendiv').css("display", "block"); 
    }else{
     $('#hiddendiv').css("display", "none"); 
   }
 });
```

As you can see I have two check boxes and I would like to display a hidden div just when the second check box has been checked or unchecked.

Can you please let me know why this is not working?

Comment: is the issue with your spelling of 'chekbox'?

Comment: Syntax error, unexpected token ';'

Comment: shouldn't you be using `radio` inputs for this?

Comment: @Tim, thanks I fixed the misspelling but still not working

Comment: Thanks Musa I find the error

Comment: You can just use .toggle() `$('#hiddendiv').toggle($('#c2').is(':checked'));` where true=show and false=hide

Comment: You should be using .prop() not .attr() since it is deprecated. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .prop() instead of .attr()

Working Example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/shGNe/2/)

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {

    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);

    if ($('#c2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#hiddendiv').css({"display" : "block"});
   } else {
        $('#hiddendiv').css({"display" : "none"});
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks VID but how I can use the toggle function to uncheck the the other(unselected) box? as you can see user can select both boxes? how we can prevent this?

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect but can you please let me know how did you do this? I mean in this line  `$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);` thanks

Comment: @user1760110 to break it down, first it looks for all checkboxes `$('input:checkbox')` , then it refines the search for all checkboxes that are NOT the one just 'clicked' `.not(this)` and finally it un-checks them all by this `.prop('checked', false)`  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error - everything else works:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/uKGkN/

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
  if($('#c2').attr('checked')){
    $('#hiddendiv').css("display", "block"); 
   }else{
    $('#hiddendiv').css("display", "none"); 
  }
}); ​
```

Comment: Thanks JSess but how I can use the toggle function to uncheck the the other(unselected) box? as you can see user can select both boxes? how we can prevent this?

Comment: You can either change them to radio buttons with the same name between each (http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/uKGkN/1/), or use jQuery to remove the checked attribute when selecting another checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues I see here

1. as noted in comments you have syntax error.
2. your logic implies that c1 and c2 values are mutually exclusive, so you really should be using `radio` inputs for this
3. `attr()` is not a good way to check if input is checked. Use `prop()` instead. See jQuery docs for diferences.

Here is a simplified [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/vYjJX/)

Comment: Hi Ilia G , Thanks for comment but how I can use this in check-boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You have some sintax problems with your code. `attr()` method is not good to get values and test like you want. Instead of it, you can use `is()` method and check if the `checked` proeprty if true. Try to do something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   $('#hiddendiv').css("display", $('#c2').is(':checked') ? "block" : "none"); 
});
```

PS: If you want to get the `sender` (checkbox changed) in the change event, you can get by `$(this)`.